# In Spider-Man 3, is the symbiote ever called Venom, or is it just in the credits?

Tags: marvel, venom, spider-man-3

Basically, is there anytime where the symbiote that is named Venom in the credits, is called Venom in the movie?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per the [film transcript](https://spidermantrilogy.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_3/Transcript), Venom is **never named or referred to as such in the film.**

He does get mentioned in the [official novelisation](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_3_(novel)), which was based on an earlier version of the screenplay

> “No. Not Eddie. Not anymore. I’m poison to you now, Spider-Man,” he
> said, flicking his tongue around. “I’m . . Venom. And I just want you
> to know, I took your advice You told me if I wanted forgiveness, I
> should find religion, so I went to church last night and asked for it.
> I asked for everything that had been taken away from me. Damned if I
> didn’t get it. And more. I was handed power I never dreamed of, Pete.
> It just… poured down on me as if from heaven itself.”
>
> “You’ve got to take off the suit!” Spider-Man told him. “It’ll—”
>
> Venom leaped to the rear of the car and kicked Spider-Man across the
> face, knocking him from the vehicle.

He's also named in various licensed products including [*Spider-Man 3: I am Venom*](https://archive.org/details/spiderman3iamven0000raym/page/n3/mode/2up), a book that was bizarrely aimed at young readers.

> [image]

and in the [*Spider-Man 3: Movie Storybook*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/569870.Spider_Man_3)

> Looking up, Eddie saw that Peter was really Spider-Man, but there was
> no time to think about that. When Eddie opened his mouth, a drop of
> the goo fell on his tongue . . . transforming him into a monstrous
> creature called Venom!
>
> Venom was born with one consuming urge: to get revenge. He began to
> form a plan, and it involved Sandman.

---

And as you've already mentioned, Venom is repeatedly referred to as "Venom" in the [end credits](https://the-jh-movie-collection-official.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_3/Credits).

> Topher Grace **as Venom**/Eddie Brock

and

> Costumes for Spider-Man, Black-Suited Spider-Man, The New Goblin,
> Sandman **and Venom** Designed by James Acheson

and

> Marvel, and all Marvel Characters including the Spider-Man, Sandman
> **and Venom** Characters TM and © 2007 Marvel Characters, Inc. All Rights
> Reserved.

Comment: The movie’s soundtrack is also Eminem’s “Venom”

Comment: @atakanyenel - I didn't know that. Do the lyrics (that are heard in the film) have the word "Venom" in them?

Comment: I dont know in fim music, but the trailer for sure has it

Comment: @atakanyenel - Hmm, I'm not sure how I feel about it being in the trailer. I'll investigate the film later.

Comment: You're thinking of Tom Hardy's Venom. The Spider-Man 3 soundtrack does not have the Eminem song.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider you are right, I completely missed that… Recency bias, I guess…

Comment: Having not seen the movie(s), what do they refer to Venom as in the movie if not "venom"? Just "Eddie Brock"?

Comment: @BruceWayne, black gooey substance